# Calculating the terminal width and height

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, node.js, console

As part of the bigger problem I am trying to solve smaller problems first and hence below is the code to find the terminal width and height.

**Code**

```
'use strict';

class Terminal {
  width() {
    return process.stdout.columns || 80
  }

  height() {
    return process.stdout.rows || 60
  }
}

module.exports = Terminal
```

How can I make the above code testable? can I use some better abstraction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the functionality of this class?
Get width and height from `process.stdout`,
an external resource,
or else fall back to default values.

You can make this testable by making it possible to inject `process.stdout`, the external resource.
Then in the test you can inject an object that you control,
and verify that `Terminal` uses that object correctly or else falls back to the defaults correctly.

To make `process.stdout` injectable, you have at least two options:

- Add an optional constructor argument. By default use `process.stdout`, only the test method will inject a custom object.
- Add a `_stdout` function, that will be used by `width` and `height`, and in the test override it appropriately.

Comment: First alternative seems better to me. Also, what could be the name of the injected argument?

Comment: @CodeYogi I would call it simply `stdout`